# const function in c++ file that accompanies header file

Tags: c++

I've started the MVA course "C++: A General Purpose Language and Library Jump Start" and I do have a question about it.

In the course there's an example about classes.
A simple class is built that describes a rectangle:

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
Rectangle() : _Width{ 1 }, _Height{ 1 } // unitialised constructor
{}

Rectangle(int initial_width, int initial_height) : _Width{            initial_width }, _Height{ initial_height } // initialised constructor
{}

int get_width() const { return _Width; }
int get_height() const { return _Height; }

void resize(int new_width, int new_height)
{
    _Width = new_width;
    _Height = new_height;
}

int get_area() const
{
    return _Width*_Height;
}

private:
int _Width, _Height;

};
```

My question is: how can I make a function ( for instance the `get_area()` function ) `const` when I only declare it in the class and do a full description in a c++ file that accompanies the header file?

I've been experimenting, but I keep getting error messages.

Comment: Hi Tom, and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be useful for us if you were more descriptive about "I keep getting error messages". For example, the full error messages, and the code that produces them. Also, please fix the formatting in your code to facilitate easier reading.

Comment: Can you please post your exact error messages?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response ! What happens is that, when I declare an instance of a rectangle in my main function:

Comment: Sigh. Courses should not teach bad habits. Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Width`, `_Height`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation and should not be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An example header (C++11):

```
// Foo.h

class Foo
{
public:    
   int f() const;

private:
   int value_ = 1;
};
```

An example implementation file:

```
// Foo.cpp

#include "Foo.h"

int Foo::f() const
{
   return value_;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response !  I tried Chad's example it turns out'I used "int const Foo::f()"  instead of "int Foo::f() const "  in the c++ file. It doesn't work. Kind regards, Tom